# Как wordpress преобразовать текстовыю ссылку в картинку

Tags: wordpress

Если в посте (допустим) есть текст типа:

```
http://Бла-Бла.Ню/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2015-10-06_12-19-311.jpg
```

Как преобразовать ее в картинку автоматически?
Типа:

```
<img class="" width="250" height="250" alt="" src="http://Бла-Бла.Ню/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2015-10-06_12-19-311.jpg">
```

Comment: Напишите свою функцию которая будет брать post_content, заменять все найденные ссылки с изображениями, и потом возвращать контент с уже линками. Но проще поискать плагины для этого, думаю такие должны быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_img_replaсe($content){
$regex = '~(?<!src=")(ht|f)tps?://[\w%#\~:;&=+,(.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))/?-]+~is';
$replace = '<img src="\\0" class="" width="250" height="250" alt="">';
return print preg_replace($regex, $replace, $content); 
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_img_replaсe');
```